# Word for "assembling information"?

Tags: single-word-requests

There's a particular word I once had in mind but now seem to have lost it, I believe it has a 'j' in it, that could be used to describe one or more of the following situations:

- looking at multiple studies on a particular topic, in order to write a piece of content
- assembling information from a number of (technical) sources and presenting it in a manner digestible to the layperson (as a reporter would do)

The word is a verb used to describe the act of doing the above (researching).

Comment: What about 'data collecting'?

Comment: Looking up synonyms that branch from *review* and *survey* I didn't see any 'j's. Regardless, you might want to have a look there...

Comment: I was going to suggest "digest" (it has a "j" sound at least) but since you use a derivative of it in your question, I'll just mention it as a comment.

Comment: @LamarLatrell: I also thought *survey paper*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No J, but for the first bullet point try:

***[Collate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/collate)***

> Collect and combine (texts, information, or data).

And for the second:

***[Disseminate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/disseminate)***

> Spread (something, especially information) widely.

(Both Oxford Dictionary)

Comment: The word I was looking for was collate, but others have made some solid suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: If we have made solid suggestions, feel free to upvote :)

Comment: I've already upvoted everyone... My status on here isn't elite enough yet for them to count. I need at least the number 15 next to my name ;)

Comment: I forgot about that! I should care less actually :). Anyway, upvoted your question, it wasn't bad !

Answer (score 1):

With letter *j*,

***to join***

> To bring together.

***to juxtapose***

> To place close together or side by side, especially for comparison or
>   contrast.

Without letter *j*, perhaps more common in this context is ***to compile***.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for **synthesis** (noun) or **synthesize** (verb) ?

- Definition : The combination and interpretation of elements to form a connected whole.
- Example: this ideology represented a synthesis of certain ideas.